# Oracle query is slower the second time

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle11g, query-performance

I have a general question about something I'm seeing in performance tuning in Oracle.  I have a query that I'm testing.  It's too big and complex for me to provide a simple example, sorry!  (I tried lowering it down, but lost the symptom)

The first time I run the query, it's 2 seconds.  Subsequent times it's 3, 4, or even 5 seconds.  This happens consistently - if I change the spacing, I get 2 seconds again, then it goes back up.

This is the opposite of what I would expect - after the first time, the database doesn't need to parse the query, and blocks should be in read into the buffer cache.  The only thing I can think of is that it is writing temp data somewhere, in such a way that it is faster to write and read it than it is to just read it.  But that of course makes no sense.

Does anyone know why this is happening?  Or any red flags in the execution plan that would cause something like this?

FYI, this is a SELECT, with multiple joins, aggregation, and views.  No internal PL/SQL.

Thank you

Comment: This is opposite of what I'd expect too.  Does the explain plan output change from run to run?

Comment: I don't think you should be [crossposting](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50594/oracle-query-is-slower-the-second-time) this...

Comment: @mustaccio - Sorry, I thought it was appropriate for the DB forum, but then I saw how many more questions in Stackoverflow matched my tags and thought I'd have better luck here.  Besides, you're the only one who answered you may get points out of it!

Comment: @Twelfth Someone else suggested this I'm taking a look thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries may produce different execution plans after the first run because of [cardinality feedback](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/cardinality_feedback).  In 12c this feature was renamed [statistics feedback](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_optcncpt.htm#TGSQL94850).

The optimizer uses information about the actual and expected number of rows from the first run, and uses that information to improve the second execution plan.  In my experience this is usually a good feature.  But all optimizer features can backfire occasionally.

There are at least two ways to tell if cardinality feedback is used.  There will be a note in the explain plan:

```
Note
-----
   - cardinality feedback used for this statement
```

Also the statement will show up in this query:

```
select * from v$sql_shared_cursor where use_feedback_stats = 'Y';
```

You may want to check both.  When I tried to create an example the query had `use_feedback_stats = 'Y'` but did not have the Note in the explain plan.

Comment: I was never able to reproduce/test, but your answer sounds good - thanks!